# Flurry alternative

Tags: iphone, analytics, tracking, usage-statistics, flurry

Is there a good alternative for Flurry ?
I use it because it is simple to integrate, but i'm not so happy with the webinterface. I miss the google-analitic-ness, but i dont want to use google.

So, what are your experiences with other analytics for iPhone ?

greets Simon

**Edit:**

- http://www.localytics.com/ Nice GUI, good API

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simon, check out Localytics (I work there). Our service is real-time, our SDKs are open source, there are both free and paid service plans, and we just released a huge update to our web interface. You can access the demo (no registration required) here: https://dashboard.localytics.com/demo

--Brian

Comment: there is just one thing i miss: event duration like flurry.

Comment: Looks like registration is required for demo....http://puu.sh/b8Xzy/8c4c6f730f.png

Answer (score 4):

There is also [HockeyApp](http://www.hockeyapp.net/).  I am comparing Flurry and HockeyApp based solely on grokking their website propaganda, and my summary is that HockeyApp is more "fix-centric", whereas Flurry is more "sales-centric:"  Dev & QA would benefit more from HockeyApp's great crash reporting features, and Product Management would benefit more from Flurry's crazy slice-and-dice analytics.  Hopefully that helps guide you based on what you are trying to accomplish.

**Update**:  I had a quick chat with the Crittercism dudes and wanted to add my findings.  Their offering seems to fill the gap between fix-centric HockeyApp, and sales-centric Flurry.  It uses the same underlying PLCrashReporter library to produce robust crash reports like HockeyApp does, and it seems to have more Flurry-like analytics than HockeyApp.  Also, pricing ... Flurry is free (though they seem to monetize through advertising on their WWW interface).  HockeyApp has pricing based on plans, starting with a $10/month plan.  Crittercism prices based on # of active users of your app and you have to work with their sales folks to eek out an actual number.

**Also update regarding support**:  HockeyApp's support is excellent; I've never waited more than 10 minutes to get a response back to my questions and the responses are succinct and accurate.  Flurry, about 24 hr turnaround and a fairly unpersonalized and lifeless response that was mostly accurate.  Crittercism has been quite fast to respond to my inquires; they have a "Chat Now!" button that put me through to the CTO, which was great for the technical questions I had.

Some key specifics and elaborations:

- HockeyApp automatically symbolicates users' crashreports on their web
  interface, and can group crashes by crashing API.  Flurry does not;
  it just shows you a bunch of raw crashes and you get to manually
  symbolicate them one instruction at a time (using `atos` -- you can't
  use `symbolicatecrash` because Flurry doesn't give you a proper
  .crash report).  Be aware that [line numbers in HockeyApp can be off
  by one or two lines](http://support.hockeyapp.net/discussions/problems/981-line-numbers-seem-to-be-off-by-1-2-lines).
- The crash reports that Flurry shows you do not include other running
  processes, whereas HockeyApp's do.  In fact, it appears that [Flurry
  crash reports are truncated](https://flurry.zendesk.com/entries/240046-larger-text-field-for-crash-error-stack-trace-reporting) to 255 characters or so.  They are anemic compared to HockeyApp.
- For crashes you mark as fixed in HockeyApp's web UI, HockeyApp can
  inform a user who subsequently experiences such a crash that the
  issue has been fixed in a new version.
- Flurry has very deep analytics prowess that HockeyApp cannot touch: 
  tracking usage stats, customer engagement, average session length,
  geographic distribution of your app, user retention over time.
- Flurry is free; HockeyApp (free up to 10 apps).  Both
  provide email support, but only HockeyApp provides a discussion
  group.  Both can record arbitrary messages (like a JSON response from
  the server that caused your app to crash) but only HockeyApp
  indicates that this message can be any length.

Alas, these are just a few random tidbits that appealed to my developer-nature and cause me to prefer HockeyApp.  I wonder what would happen if I used both in my app!

If you have 7 minutes, HockeyApp has [a video walkthrough](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=U6Jon0ombSk) that I found quite useful.

Answer (score 4):

AskingPoint.com (I work there and am the founder).

1. Not free, now starts at 49$ (supports iOS and Android APPS)
2. Has the following capabilities:

   1. Basic Analytics
   2. Unlimited Named Custom Events with or without data.
   3. Unlimited Timed Events with or without data.
   4. In-App Msgs and Push Notifications
   5. Monetization tools (Ads, Cross Promotion)
3. A Dashboard.
4. An embedded Ratings widget that is controlled from your account dashboard, uses your analytics and is translated into 30 languages.
5. Free Data Export (all data).
6. Fast and easy integration.
7. We have an App for viewing your data on the go, and our web interface does NOT use flash so you can alternatively view your dashboard on your iPad or iPhone in a browser... but use our app instead.

We don't and won't sell your data. We are free because we plan on eventually making our money from an opt-in service that we will charge third parties for the revenue from which we will share with the Apps that participated and helped generate it.

Answer (score 2):

Cobub Razor is an open source free system like Flurry. And it opens both SDK and web side source codes.

Demo:    http://demo.cobub.com/razor/en

GitHub:  http://www.github.com/cobub/razor

Answer (score 0):

Mixpanel, I have heard a lot of good thing about their product https://mixpanel.com/